# How to remove rownames from a heatmap2?

Tags: r, data-visualization, heatmap

I basically want to merge two heatmap2's. So in this course I want to hide the rownames of the first graph. I tried removing rownames from the data frame but they do not get removed. Is there some way I can do the same?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include some form of [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample data and the code you are using to make your plot.

Answer (score 0):

Set `labRow` to `NULL`

```
labRow=NULL
```